# code changes when migrating from MyISAM to Innodb

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, innodb, myisam

I am just wondering do I need to alter "ruby on rails" code when migrating from MyISAM to InnoDB.

I want to migrate to InnoDB and it's known that deadlock is something that may happen working with InnoDB, do I need somehow threat all my **inserts** and **updates** to DB.

By now, I used just standard methods of ActiveRecord without using transactions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my point of view that should be possible without any problems. Migrate to InnoDB, run your tests and see if anything breaks. From my history of standard Rails projects I never ran into issues with deadlocks. But at the end it depends on the code you've written. There is no other way than trying it out.